# How to get GDAX transfer information from API?

Tags: php, api

When you initiate a withdrawal through the API via `POST /withdrawals/crypto` you will get an id in the response. My guesses are that is the transfer id.

When you go the GDAX web interface and go to accounts you will find more details:

```
Transfer ID: <transfer-id>
Estimated Payout: <estimated payout date>
BTC transaction hash: <hash>
```

I am especially interested in the BTC transaction hash part to follow it's process, does anyone have an idea how to retrieve the transfer details?